# Change behavior of Chrome search bar autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has its annoyances, but for the most part it's okay.

Except when it autocompletes the text that I type into the address/search bar.

Instead of typing something like "atom", hitting Enter, and realizing that Chrome has decided to search for "atomic mass of Einsteinium" instead of "atom" simply because I've searched for it before, I want to type "atom", still have the autocomplete, and have the option for tab completion.

Does this exist? Can this be changed? Can Chrome be slightly less annoying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, but the Chromium team has always refused to provide a way to disable the inline autocomplete feature in Chrome:

> "the code and UX complexity of this is nontrivial because inline
>   autocompletion is the central design feature around which all other
>   omnibox decisions are based."
>   https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667922#c8

You should create a report at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list (click the "New Issue" button near the logo) to ask for that feature.

Maybe if enough people do that they'll consider providing that option.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was trying to get people annoyed by that feature to go complain to the chromium devs.